# Network connection settings on Android TV emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to turn off network connection on Android TV emulator.

I found: Settings -> Network -> Wifi on/off, but I still have internet for my emulator device. Is there some shortcut (iMac) or easy terminal command that would disable network?

Running `./adb shell am broadcast -a` gives me this messageL

```
android.intent.action.WIFI_OFF
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.WIFI_OFF }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

But I still have network connection on my emulator.

Comment: It's an interesting question! Most programmers just toggle "airplane mode" to disable the internet on an emulated device, but that might not be possible for Android-TV. I recall using a function key (F8) before to disable the internet connection on an emulated device, but that doesn't seem to work any more. I'm curious to see if anyone offers a good answer to this question! Meanwhile, if you're desperate, you could just toggle the WiFi connection on your development machine (which will of course also disable the emulated device's internet connection).

Comment: turning off the wifi does the trick for me.  When i do `adb shell ping www.google.com` after turning off the wifi, there is no connection. It's weird that your emulator is still connected.

Answer (score 0):

if it is rooted device then use the below code to disable the  network

```
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c svc data disable");
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
}
```

again want to enable simply change **disable** to **enable**

in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**OR**

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Use the below one to check enabled or not

```
boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
```

Permissions in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```